# Iterate over column to meet criteria

Tags: r

My data.frame "Analysis" is 180,010 obs of 7 variables. An abbreviated example of it's structure is as follows:

```
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
Rating <- c("Poor", "Excellent", "Very Good", "Poor", "Good", "Fair", 
            "Very Good", "Fair", "Poor", "Excellent")
Speed <- c(10, 19, 20, 21, 22, 20, 20, 21, 23, 15)
```

I wish to loop through "Analysis$Speed" and find all occurrences that are equal to or higher than 19 and equal to or lower 25. There should be a minimum of 4 or more consecutive values that fit this criteria - if there are 3, these values are disregarded. I wish to create a new data.frame "Output" that contains the values and their respective "ID", "Rating" and "Speed" but I am unsure how to do so.

As an example, from the above:

```
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
Rating <- c("Excellent", "Very Good", "Poor", "Good", "Fair", "Very 
            Good", "Fair", "Poor")
Speed <- c(19, 20, 21, 22, 20, 20, 21, 23)
```

My experience in writing loops is very limited (none) and most questions are with quantitative data or searching for strings, whilst mine is a mixture.

Comment: Your description says `find all occurrences that are equal to or lower than 19`.  I am not sure how `19` is included in the expected output.

Comment: @akrun Thank you for noticing this error. I have clarified the question to reflect: equal to or > 19 and equal to or < 25.

Comment: The output remains the same.  Can you check if the solution provided below works for you?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
Rating <- c("Poor", "Excellent", "Very Good", "Poor", "Good", "Fair", 
            "Very Good", "Fair", "Poor", "Excellent")
Speed <- c(10, 19, 20, 21, 22, 20, 20, 21, 23, 15)

ID2 <- c()
Rating2 <- c()
Speed2 <- c()

for (i in 1:length(Speed)) {
  if (Speed[i] >= 25 | Speed[i] <= 19){
    ID2 <- c(ID2,ID[i])
    Rating2 <- c(Rating2,Rating[i])
    Speed2 <- c(Speed2, Speed[i])
  }
}

Output <- data.frame(ID = ID2, Rating = Rating2, Speed = Speed2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 'ID' is a grouping variable and "Speed <=19" would be instead "Speed < 19", we can use `ave` with `rle` to get the logical index of consecutive elements > 3 using the condition ( "Speed < 19 | Speed >=25"), and use that index to subset the original dataset.

```
f1 <- function(dat,Var1 , Var2){
   indx <- as.logical(with(dat, ave(Var2, Var1, FUN=function(x) {
        inverse.rle(within.list(rle(x < 19 | x>=25),
              values <- lengths[values] >3 |!values))})))
   dat[indx,]
}

f1(Analysis, ID, Speed)
#   ID    Rating Speed
#2  1 Excellent    19
#3  1 Very Good    20
#4  1      Poor    21
#5  1      Good    22
#6  2      Fair    20
#7  2 Very Good    20
#8  2      Fair    21
#9  2      Poor    23
```

Using another example (having more than 3 consecutive elements that fits the condition)

```
f1(AnalysisN, ID, Speed)
#    ID    Rating Speed
#2   1 Excellent    20
#3   1 Excellent    15
#4   1 Excellent    27
#5   1 Excellent    19
#6   2      Poor    22
#7   2      Fair    14
#8   2      Poor    20
#9   2      Fair    22
#12  3 Excellent    11
#13  3 Very Good    18
#14  3      Fair    10
#15  3      Poor    15
#16  4      Fair    19
#17  4 Excellent    23
#18  4      Fair    26
#19  4 Very Good    20
#22  5 Very Good    26
#23  5      Poor    15
#24  5 Excellent    29
#25  5 Excellent    13
```

#### data

```
Analysis <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
Rating = c("Poor", 
"Excellent", "Very Good", "Poor", "Good", "Fair", "Very Good", 
"Fair", "Poor", "Excellent"), Speed = c(10, 19, 20, 21, 22, 20, 
20, 21, 23, 15)), .Names = c("ID", "Rating", "Speed"), 
row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

 set.seed(30)
 AnalysisN <- data.frame(ID= rep(1:5, each=5), 
 Rating= sample(c('Poor', 'Excellent', 'Very Good', 'Fair'), 25, 
 replace=TRUE), Speed =sample(10:30, 25, replace=TRUE), 
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: When I run your function on my `data.frame` (using the correct column names, instead of the example given), an error is returned stating that "Error in interaction(...) : object `ID` not found. My column was an integer, so I have converted to a numeric although am still receiving the same error. Unsure what is wrong?

Comment: @user2716568 It may be better to update your post a small example using `dput` that gives the error.  In that way, it would be easier to find the problem.  Based on the `Error`, the `ID` column is not present in your dataset.  So, it may be another 'name`?